# Playing audio through the microphone

Tags: c#

I have been looking for a long time on how to play audio (in this case audio files) through the microphone, with no success. How could I do that? I'm trying to make something like a soundboard, I hope you can understand my goal.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: To make things clear, imagine you are in a voice call and you want to play a sound for the other person to hear, I want to play the sound so applications register like its coming from the microphone while also registering input from the mic, basically a soundboard.

Comment: A microphone is used to record audio not play it. Can you clarify your intent?

Comment: Since you mentioned making a soundboard, I'm going to assume you mean that you want to send audio from your application through an audio input device and not literally play something through the microphone. I tried this at one point and quickly found out it's a lot more complicated than it sounds. You would have to create a virtual device driver, which you would have to do in C/C++. If you don't want to do that (it's a lot more work than it's worth IMO), I'm sure you could use a third-party application like [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/) to do it.

Comment: You might want to investigate if [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) can mix microphone and other audio inputs.

Comment: mm it's a strange one... may be you should provide more context - when do you need this?

for example if you are creating a calling app and imagine two users are in call - you can send some event from one device to another and the device that receives an event may play some audio on his side